# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources$Theme android.content.Context.getTheme()' on a null object reference (Fragment)

Tags: android, fragment, android-alertdialog

This is the java file code for fragment:

```
@SuppressLint({"NewApi", "ResourceAsColor"})
public void createCardView(String id, String date, final String order) {
    flag = true;
    cardView = new CardView(context);
    cardView.setLayoutParams(layoutParamsCard);
    cardView.setElevation(5);
    relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(context);
    relativeLayout.setLayoutParams(layoutParamsRelative);
    textView = new TextView(context);
    orderID = new TextView(context);
    textView.setLayoutParams(layoutParamsTextView);
    textView.setText("Order ID:");
    textView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#1e1e1e"));
    textView.setTypeface(Typeface.defaultFromStyle(Typeface.BOLD));
    orderID.setLayoutParams(layoutParamsTextViewID);
    orderID.setText(id);
    orderID.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#646464"));
    orderID.setTypeface(Typeface.defaultFromStyle(Typeface.BOLD));
    orderDate = new TextView(context);
    orderDate.setText(date);
    orderDate.setLayoutParams(layoutParamsOrderDate);
    viewOrder = new Button(context);
    viewOrder.setText("View Order");
    viewOrder.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
    viewOrder.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#326432"));
    viewOrder.setLayoutParams(layoutParamsViewOrder);
    viewOrder.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            final View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_order_dialog,null);
            dialogBuilder.setView(dialogView);
            final TextView orderTextView = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.orderTextView);
            final Button close = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.close);
            orderTextView.setText(order);
            dialogBuilder.setTitle("Order ID: " + orderID.getText().toString());
            final AlertDialog alertDialog = dialogBuilder.create();
            alertDialog.show();
        }
    });
    cardView.addView(relativeLayout);
    relativeLayout.addView(textView);
    relativeLayout.addView(orderID);
    relativeLayout.addView(viewOrder);
    relativeLayout.addView(orderDate);
    gridLayout.addView(cardView);
}
```

I am not able to launch custom dialogview from fragment. It crashes the app when i open that fragment. I am using this code to create cards dynamically and creating an OnClickListner for each card.

Comment: `getTheme()' on a null object reference (Fragment)` There is no `getTheme` method in pasted codes. Maybe you are trying to set theme before inflating or ?

Comment: Tried getApplicationContext() instead of getActivity(), but still not happening.

Comment: AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());

Comment: Error comes from something else. Would you paste the `Fragment` code + logcat here?

Comment: i am not using getTheme() method anywhere.

Comment: post full stack trace

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Your activity **`context`** is null in this line :

```
AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity()); // getActivity() is getting null here
```

To avoid crash, you should wrap your code and check if your activity context is not null like this :

```
if(getActivity() != null){
   AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
   LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
   final View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_order_dialog,null);
   dialogBuilder.setView(dialogView);
   final TextView orderTextView = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.orderTextView);
   orderTextView.setText(order);
   final AlertDialog alertDialog = dialogBuilder.create();
   alertDialog.show();
}
```

Comment: Are you sure? `Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources$Theme android.content.Context.getTheme()' on a null object reference (Fragment)` **getTheme()** !!

Comment: Yes, if it's `NullPointerException` then it's related to your `context`. (More i can tell from looking into entire code and logcat) @ʍѳђઽ૯ท

Comment: how can i fix it.

Comment: Thanks. i got it. Actually i was placing that line in instance level. Now it works. Thanks for giving me clue. THUMS UP

Comment: Happy to help :)

Comment: that's true. It may lost activity before dialog be shown

Answer (score 1):

In My Case this type of error is showing in case of displaying Dialog on the RecyclerView item click.

**1)Define Activity in your class like this:-**

```
       // Initialize activity
       Activity activity;

      // define activity of this class//
        activity=EditFieldsActivity.this;
```

**2)Pass this activity in your Adapter Like this:-**

```
EditFieldAdapter adapter = new EditFieldAdapter(getApplicationContext(),data,activity);
recyclerFieldManagement.setAdapter(adapter);
```

**3)And Get This activity in your adapter and use activity for showing Dialog as:-**

```
private Activity activity;
    public EditFieldAdapter(Context applicationContext, List<FieldDetails> data, Activity activity) {
        this.ctx=applicationContext;
        this.data=data;
        this.activity=activity;
    }
```

Hope this will help you.Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

If you use `YourActivityName.this` instead of `context`, your problem will be solved.
For example ;

```
final AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                alertDialog.setTitle("Take a Note ");
```

> ```
>                                    or
> ```

```
final EditText edtText = new EditText(MainActivity.this);
                edtText.setText("editText");
                parent.addView(edtText);
```

Comment: doesn't work. I get "MainActivity.this is not an enclosing class "